# MongoDB Stored my date with the wrong time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, momentjs

I recently tried to assign a new date in MongoDB, but I have a problem with that, it stored the date I give but it's not correct

```
userSchema.methods.createPasswordResetToken = async function () {
  this.passwordResetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
  this.passwordResetExpires = moment().format(this.createAt)

  await this.save()
  
  console.log(moment().format(this.createAt)) // 2021-12-21T19:01:54+02:00
  console.log(this.passwordResetExpires) // 2021-12-21T17:01:54.000Z 
  
  return { token: this.passwordResetToken, userId: this._id }
}
```

mongoDb remove 2 hours when storing it

and when I try to catch the type of two values
I got

```
  console.log(moment().format(this.createAt)) // string
  console.log(this.passwordResetExpires) // object
```

:

user Schema

```
...
passwordResetToken: String,
passwordResetExpires: Date
...
```

Comment: Don't pass date as string, use `this.passwordResetExpires = moment().toDate()`

Comment: What is `this.createAt`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/#overview):

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic.

It seems your server just sits in GMT timezone ( utc +2, you could also see it from your date value `// 2021-12-21T19:01:54+02:00` ). I would usually offer some hacky way to get around the issue but this is actually a best practice. Hence I recommend you do your date calculations in UTC and not in machine time.

- note your other date is in UTC (`2021-12-21T17:01:54.000Z`), make sure your comparing apples to apples.